# Не работает код, запутался в циклах

Tags: c++, linux, visual-c++

Хочу написать программу, которая будет радномизировать 20 чисел и вносить их в массив (по одному числу в одну ячейку массива), но при этом в массиве не должно быть повторяющихся чисел. Как результат я хочу увидеть 20 разных чисел, но ничего не происходит. Мне кажется что проблема находится где-то после 11-й строки. Функции rand и srand проверял, со стандартной библиотекой c++ они работают. Скорее всего код вам покажется плохим, но я был бы очень признатален если вы мне поможете. Решил проблему таким образом

```
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  int SIZE = 20;
  int arr[SIZE];
  srand (time (NULL));
  bool value;
  int i, j;
  value = true;
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
      while (value = true)
    {
      arr[i] = rand () % 20;
      if (i > 0)
        {
          for (j = i; j >= 0; j--)
        {
          if (arr[i] = arr[j])
            {
              value = true;
            }
        }
        }
    }

      cout << arr[i] << "\n";
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (value = true)` — этот цикл никогда не завершится, потому что такое присваивание всегда возвращает true

Comment: `if (arr[i] = arr[j])` — это присваивание уничтожает предыдущий arr[i]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вложенные циклы не желательны. Вот алгоритм где цифры просто перемешиваются за один цикл - не нужно никаких сравнений уникальности.
Код выглядит короче и понятнее;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define SIZE 20    

int main () {
    int i, arr[SIZE];
    srand (time (NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) arr[i] = i;  // [0...SIZE-1]

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        int t = arr[0];          // временно сохраняем число arr[0]
        int idx = rand() % SIZE; // генерим случайный индекс
        arr[0] = arr[idx];       // из arr[idx] число помещаем в arr[0]
        arr[idx] = t;            // в arr[idx] число из [0]
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) cout << arr[i] << endl;     

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос в том, должны ли эти 20 чисел быть именно 0..19. А может, они должны быть из иного диапазона или подчиняться какому-то распределению? Автор вопроса забыл об этом сказать...